# integration of ntopng on aws centos

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to run ntopng on an AWS instance (centos) to monitor my local network
So my questions are:

1. How to connect my local network to aws ntopng located in aws instance.
2. how to integrate n2disk, nprobe cento and ntopng together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues: 1) Connecting an Amazon VPC to your local network 2) snooping on network traffic.

You can setup a VPN to connect your networks together. Consider using OpenSwan or Windows Server setup on each side of the network.

Network Snooping: This is not possible in Amazon VPCs. Network interfaces cannot be put into promiscuous mode. Also, this is FORBIDDEN by Amazon policies.

Note: You can monitor your own traffic using VPC Flowlogs. This will show you higher level packet information, but will not include the data portion.

Comment: You're right, except possibly about it being *"forbidden"*... the documentation, in at least one place, states that it is permitted, but pointless: [*"It is not possible for a virtual instance running in promiscuous mode to receive or sniff traffic that is intended for a different virtual instance.* **While customers can elect to place their interfaces into promiscuous mode,** *the hypervisor will not deliver any traffic to an instance that is not addressed to it."*](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/vpc-security-capabilities/)

Comment: Michael, FYI: the Amazon Acceptable Use Policy document "prohibits" these type of activities as security violations: https://aws.amazon.com/aup/

Comment: I'm with you, but putting an interface into promiscuous mode is not mentioned (and not harmful).  Perhaps I misread your statement and you are saying that snooping in general (rather than promiscuous mode, specifically) is forbidden, in which case you'd be right, because snooping would require deliberate attempts to breach the established infrastructure's intrinsic ability to prevent this.  [A Day in the Life of a Billion Packets](https://youtu.be/Zd5hsL-JNY4) and its follow-ups are excellent views into the inner-workings of the network implementation, for anyone who hasn't seen them.